# Is it possible to create a dedicated resource solely for the uptime monitoring of all my synthetic monitors with a common tag?

Tags: datadog

I'm looking to optimize my monitoring setup on AWS and DataDog. I'm wondering if there's a way to establish a dedicated resource specifically for tracking the uptime of all my synthetic monitors that share a common tag. Additionally, I've been attempting to replicate the Global Uptime feature that the Synthetic Home provides, but I'm struggling to recreate the exact query that DataDog uses by default in their synthetic home. Any insights or guidance on this, especially regarding replicating DataDog's default synthetic home query, would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely! You can create a dedicated resource for monitoring the uptime of your synthetic monitors with a common tag by employing various tools and methods.

One efficient way is to utilize monitoring services or platforms that support tagging or labeling of resources. These platforms often allow you to group and organize monitors based on specific tags. By tagging your synthetic monitors with a common identifier, you can then create a dedicated resource or dashboard within the monitoring tool to display the status and uptime of all monitors associated with that tag.

For instance, if you're using a service like Datadog, New Relic, or Prometheus for monitoring, they often support tagging or labeling mechanisms. You can tag your synthetic monitors with a shared label, and then create a dashboard or a dedicated view that filters and displays only the monitors with that particular tag.

Alternatively, you can develop custom scripts or applications that interact with the monitoring APIs provided by the service you're using. These scripts can query the status of monitors based on their tags and display the uptime information in a centralized dashboard or resource that you create.

Remember, the specific method you choose may depend on the monitoring tools or services you're utilizing, as different platforms have different features and capabilities for organizing and managing monitors.